# Cirq compilation process

Tags: cirq, compiling

[Cirq](https://Cirq%20compilation%20process) compilation process.

I cannot find the documentation that describes the internal structure of [the library Cirq by Google](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq).

There is much information related to high level functions, but none related to the compiler step and how the circuit is decomposed, and translated to an Intermediate Representation. If someone knows, where to find this information it would be very helpful?